# Embed .mov file via 'Add Media' not working

Tags: embed, video-player

I know since WP 3.6 we've been able to upload and embed various file formats and that the 'Add Media' button effectively implements the correct media embed shortcode for us.

I'm having a problem in WP4.0 using 'Add Media' to embed quicktime (.mov) files. The embed works fine for the other supported video MIME types but I'm not offered 'Embed Media Player' when I try adding a .mov file to a post.

See screen grabs/explanation:
[image: Screenshot]

See how .mov embed has reverted to a simple hyperlink (recorders) at [this page](http://www.hollandparkprimary.org.uk/2014/10/4c-learn-play-recorders/)

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is, or to a possible fix so I can embed .mov as easily as .mp4 - seems to be the preferred format of the client. For the moment we're having to manually add the [video] shortcode ourselves in the text editor.

How do I check that embed is supported/enabled for .mov?

Answer (score 7):

You can try the following:

```
/**
 * Add support for the QuickTime (.mov) video format.
 */
add_filter( 'wp_video_extensions', 
    function( $exts ) {
        $exts[] = 'mov';
        return $exts;
    }
);
```

to add the *Embed Media Player* support for the QuickTime video files.

The [default](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/media.php#L1655) supported video formats are:

```
mp4, m4v, webm, ogv, wmv, flv
```

### Update:

When I test this I get the `Embed Media Player` option and following shortcode inserted into the post:

```
[video width="240" 
       height="180" 
       mov="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/video1.mov"][/video]
```

Similar for the `.avi` and `.wmv` extensions:

```
[video width="160" 
       height="120" 
       avi="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/video2.avi"][/video]


[video width="1280" 
       height="720" 
       wmv="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/video3.wmv"][/video]
```

Comment: Does this work for avi as well. Haven't tested this nor am I able to test it now

Comment: Good question, maybe I can test it later today @PieterGoosen

Comment: @PieterGoosen I can confirm that the "Embed Media Player" option shows up after this, but I didn't try to play it since I don't think I got the browser support for these formats.

Comment: Great, that works. It does seems that you need a special media player to play the files though.

Comment: Nope. Tested .mov video and works using the video shortcodes without the filter.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @BradDalton. Without the above filter, I don't get the *"Embed Media Player"* option for `.mov` files and I only get a link to the file on the front-end. With the above filter I can see the player on the front-end but can't play it, only download it from the link in the top left corner. I think that's because I don't  have *QuickTime* support in my browser.

Comment: @birgire My bad. Didn't test on Chrome only Safari which supports QuickTime.

Comment: ok no problem and I was just too lazy setting up QT to test ;-) @BradDalton

Comment: This definitely works!!! BUT is there a way to put a thumbnail? right now, it only shows the plya button which is fine, but i'd like to put a thumbnail.

Comment: Check out the poster attribute for the video shortcode @Alejo_Blue

Answer (score 0):

Not very beautiful but work for me - just hartcode " **type="video/mp4"**>