# Adding .mov files (not from YouTube)

Tags: media

Brand new to WordPress. Using it from GoDaddy and when I try to upload my video .mov file (it's only 10MB) I get an error saying it's not a valid media type. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: try some other format videos.

Comment: IMO, I wouldn't upload videos directly into WP, using a provider ( vimeo, youtube, etc ) is usually faster and more reliable in the long run.

Comment: If you are hosting with GoDaddy's WP plan, it's possible that they block certain formats for their own sake. So first, I would check if .mov is listed as an allowed mime type. See the codex on how to get that list -> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_allowed_mime_types

Answer (score 1):

You can use `upload_mimes` filter and add mime for .mov files (`video/quicktime`).

```
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'customizeMimeTypes', 10, 1 );
function customizeMimeTypes( $mimeTypes) {
    $mimeTypes['mov'] = 'video/quicktime';
    return $mimeTypes;
}
```

If you want to embed video with media library you can use `wp_video_extensions` filter.

```
add_filter( 'wp_video_extensions', 'addMovToWPVideo');
function addMovToWPVideo( $extensions ) {
    $extensions [] = 'mov';
    return $extensions ;
}
```

More info:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_video_extensions/
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/upload_mimes

Hope this helps you!

Note: check php max upload file size in php.ini too!

Answer (score 0):

Check this another stack [thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165706/embed-mov-file-via-add-media-not-working) it having same discussion and solution.

Thanks

Vee

Comment: That's not the case here, that user was able to upload a .mov file, but this user isn't. Else this question would be closed as a duplicate